# Rstudio does not launch in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: qt, opengl, rstudio

I have installed R 4

```
$ R

R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) -- "Kick Things"
```

and then Rstudio from the [installer](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/). The software centre shows the installation as correct, I have the icon on the application bar, yet, when I click on it, it does not start. From terminal I get:

```
$ rstudio
WebEngineContext used before QtWebEngine::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed.
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DefaultSwapBehavior, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What could be the problem?

Thank you

PS: the video characteristics are:

```
$ lspci -k | egrep -A3 "VGA|3D|Video"
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 730] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GK208B [GeForce GT 730]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
$ lsmod | grep drm
nvidia_drm             57344  5
nvidia_modeset       1228800  7 nvidia_drm
drm_kms_helper        245760  1 nvidia_drm
cec                    53248  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   552960  8 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
```

By running the suggested command I got:

```
$ wget -c https://rstudio.org/download/latest/stable/desktop/bionic/rstudio-latest-amd64.deb && sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-latest-amd64.deb
--2021-09-19 12:05:03--  https://rstudio.org/download/latest/stable/desktop/bionic/rstudio-latest-amd64.deb
Resolving rstudio.org (rstudio.org)... 45.33.2.142
Connecting to rstudio.org (rstudio.org)|45.33.2.142|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-desktop/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb [following]
--2021-09-19 12:05:04--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-desktop/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.217.82.238
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|52.217.82.238|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 122505496 (117M) [application/x-deb]
Saving to: ‘rstudio-latest-amd64.deb’

rstudio-latest-amd6 100%[===================>] 116,83M  11,9MB/s    in 12s     

2021-09-19 12:05:16 (9,61 MB/s) - ‘rstudio-latest-amd64.deb’ saved [122505496/122505496]

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'rstudio' instead of './rstudio-latest-amd64.deb'
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm11
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  rstudio
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 831 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /home/gigiux/rstudio-latest-amd64.deb rstudio amd64 1.4.1717 [123 MB]
Selecting previously unselected package rstudio.
(Reading database ... 197622 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rstudio-latest-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rstudio (1.4.1717) ...
Setting up rstudio (1.4.1717) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.68ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.0-1) ...
W: Repository is broken: rstudio:amd64 (= 1.4.1717) has no Size information
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/gigiux/rstudio-latest-amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem with latest RStudio installed by `wget -c https://rstudio.org/download/latest/stable/desktop/bionic/rstudio-latest-amd64.deb && sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-latest-amd64.deb` ? Which video adapter and video driver do you have? Please add output of `lspci -k | egrep -A3 "VGA|3D|Video"` and `lsmod | grep drm` to the question.

Comment: Thank you. I understood I got already the latest version since I downloaded the installer from Rstudio website...

Comment: But despite the error (see updated question) Rstudio has launched! So error solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall really newest RStudio by using below commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rstudio --no-sandbox`